# Secondary command buffer for rendering in vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

Is it possible to make the rendering happen in the secondary command buffers? For example, there are 3 primary buffers and they call secondary buffers, which in turn render? I want to make a simple Manager that allows you to add and remove new objects on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And when using secondary command buffers and the `VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS` flag for your renderpass (see [VkSubpassContents](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassContents.html)) you actually have to put all rendering commands into secondary command buffers that are called from within the primary command buffer using `vkCmdExecuteCommands`.